# Can't detect Right Click on listBox in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I don't understand why I can't detect right click on my list box when I use an MVVM.
I use the event trigger but some events doesn't work.

```
<ListBox x:Name="PlaylistsList" ItemsSource="{Binding PlaylistsList}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseRightButtonDown">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding NewPlaylistCommand}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListBox>
```

My command "NewPlaylistCommand" is never call. Could you help me ?
Thank you.

EDIT:
I found solution to my problem, I used the ContextMenu to interact with my ListBoxItem

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel x:Name="ListBox">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="Rename" Command="{Binding RenamePlaylistCommand}"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Delete" Command="{Binding DeletePlaylistCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedValue, ElementName=PlaylistsList}"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Now I can right click on my item to Rename or Delete it.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the output window detailing invalid binding expressions?

Comment: No errors in the output window

Comment: I have no solution to your actual problem, but the fact that you are trying to capture a right click on a menu item suggest that you want to display an menu to interact on this item. Am I right?

Comment: I found solution. Thank you for your help. I edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely that something inside has swallowed your right click event and hence it has not bubbled up (I suspect it has something to do with context menu behaviors). You COULD use the Preview- events which bubble the other way.

The other solution you could use is to directly apply the interaction to each and every child in the list box (and their children as well).

However I honestly don't expect from a UI point of view that right clicking on a play list will create a new play list...I expect from my years of windows usage that a context menu should pop up, possibly with an "add new play list" menuitem.

Comment: I already have a menuitem to add a new Playlist, I would like right click an item to Rename or Delete it.